# Selector $(body) works but break the code (reference error) while $("body") shows no error but dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a JS function that I need to be called on window resize.
The only way I found to get this working is by using:

```
    $(body).on('resize', function(){
        myFunction();
    });
```

With this, myFunction() is executed on window resize.
The problem is that I get a reference error (body is not defined), so the rest of my JS isn't executed properly.

I tried different selectors: $("body"), $("document.body"), $(window), $(document),... With them I get no reference error, but the function is not executed.

Here's what looks like ( minimal view ) my html:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        [ Alot of things ...]
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, jQuery is included in my head section, while my JS is included before closing body tag.

Now this is what looks like my main.js file:

```
myFunction(){
    alert("Hello world");
}

$(body).on('resize', function(){
    myFunction();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    myFunction();
}
```

Function works properly on page load ( with $(document).ready ) but I need it to run on each page resize.
I searched a lot to solve my problem, but I'm stuck. I apologize if the answer is trivial. I'm kind of a noob with JS and DOM elements selectors.

**Edit with some more infos:**
The function in question is used to set multiple div to an equal height.
You can found it here [Equal Height divs with jQuery](http://www.leonamarant.com/2009/04/29/equal-height-divs-with-jquery/).
My div group are rows of skelJS grid system.

So the initial problem was that when i was resizing my window, divs where not resized to fit the responsive font-size, so I get an overflow.
Obviously I tried to call that function on window/body resize, but I can't get it to work EXCEPT if I use $(body) selector, which gives me an reference error, but then the overflow problem disappear and function properly runs on resize.. It's really strange. I tried all of your solutions, nothing seems to work.

Comment: `$(window).resize(myFunction)` should work.

Comment: because there is no `body` global.

Comment: SideNote: `$(body)` will throw error if `body`(_variable_) is not defined. If you refer `<body>`, use `$('body')` or `$(document.body)`.

Comment: Unfortaly   $(window).resize(function(){myFunction()}); dont works, maybe i do it wrong ?

Comment: The overflow might comes from you CSS instead? Maybe you can provide full code using the snippet.

Comment: So in the end the issue has nothing to do with resize, the issue has to do with the code that was unseen when originally posted being wrong. I updated my answer fixing the broken 3rd party code that was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be attaching the resize to the window, not to the document.body.

```js
(function() {
    function resizeFnc() {
        console.log("resized called");
    }

    $(window).on("resize", resizeFnc); //calls it on resize
    $(resizeFnc); //calls it on document ready

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The reason why `$(body)` fails is there is no variable "body" declared. The reasn why `$("body")` and `$(document.body)` fail is the event is not triggered on the body so it is not called.

---

And with the code you linked to.

```js
function equalHeight(group) {
    console.log("I was called");
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}
 
$(function(){
    equalHeight($(".EqHeightDiv"));
});

$(window).on("resize", function(){
    console.log("resized called");
    equalHeight($(".EqHeightDiv"));
});
```

```css
.EqHeightDiv { width: 30% ;box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="EqHeightDiv" style="float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:10px;">Here is some stuff</div>
<div class="EqHeightDiv" style="float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:10px;">Here is some stuff<br />Here is some stuff</div>
<div class="EqHeightDiv" style="float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:10px;">Here is some stuff<br />Here is some stu<br />Here is some stuff</div>
```

**Now what is broken is the script you are using. Resize is called, it just is not setting the new max height.** So as stated window resize is being triggered, the problem was somewhere else.

**So how do we fix this?**

```js
var timer;
function equalHeight(group) {
  
    if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer); //so this code is not called on every single resize
    timer = window.setTimeout( function () {
        var tallest = 0;
        group.height("");  //reset the heights
        group.each(function() {
            thisHeight = $(this).height();
            if(thisHeight > tallest) {
                tallest = thisHeight;
            }
        });
        group.height(tallest);
    }, 10);  
}
 
$(function(){
    equalHeight($(".EqHeightDiv"));
});

$(window).on("resize", function(){
    equalHeight($(".EqHeightDiv"));
});
```

```css
.EqHeightDiv { width: 30% ;box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="EqHeightDiv" style="float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:10px;">Here is some stuff</div>
<div class="EqHeightDiv" style="float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:10px;">Here is some stuff<br />Here is some stuff</div>
<div class="EqHeightDiv" style="float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:10px;">Here is some stuff<br />Here is some stu<br />Here is some stuff</div>
```

Comment: OP said that he has already used `$(window)` and it didn't work, can you explain why. _I tried different selectors: `$("body")`, `$("document.body")`, `$(window)`, `$(document)`,... With them i get no reference error, but the function is not executed._

Comment: Without seeing what they actaully did with the full code, I have no clue why it magically did not get called. The above code should work and changed it to be runnable to prove it works.

Comment: This solved my problem ! Thanks alot ! I will just add, in case someone's facing the same problem (equalheight with skeljs grid system): I didnt had to use your css nor the class EqHeightDiv, as the positioning is handled by skelJS. But i know it was required for your code snippet to be completely clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Window is a global object and should not have any reference error

```
function myFunction(){
        alert("Hello world");
    } 



$(window).resize(function() { 
  myFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        myFunction();
    });
});`

Here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/6t987c28/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change or add a class to `<body>`, then it should be done in your function instead of the resize jQuery:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    $('body').css('background', 'green');
    // or
    $('body').addClass('selector-name');
}
```